# What cause of 'formal parameter name expected' occured in this case?

Tags: dart

I run the code below and I got an error without any stack trace.

My code:

```dart
typedef Check<T>(T value, [onError(T value)]);

main () {
  List<Check> checks = [
    (str) => str != null,
    (str) => !str.isEmpty
  ];

  Check<String> doCheck = (String value, [onError(String)]) {
    checks.forEach((Check check) {
      if (?onError) {
        check(value, onError);
      } else {
        check(value);
      }
    });
  };

  doCheck("10");
}
```

And, the error I got.

```
file:///..()../sample.dart': Error: line 11 pos 12: formal parameter name expected
if (?onError) {
```

I want to get `onError` as an optional parameter in `doCheck` function, and pass this parameter to other functions in `checks`.

I confirmed to forward an optional parameter to 'one' function...

Is this one of restrictions to optional parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is a bug (see [issue 8007](http://dartbug.com/8007)). To work around it, you have to use a temporary variable :

```dart
typedef Check<T>(T value, [onError(T value)]);

main () {
  List<Check> checks = [
    (str) => str != null,
    (str) => !str.isEmpty
  ];

  Check<String> doCheck = (String value, [onError(String)]) {
    final isOnErrorPresent = ?onError;
    checks.forEach((Check check) {
      if (isOnErrorPresent) {
        check(value, onError);
      } else {
        check(value);
      }
    });
  };

  doCheck("10");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice to solve!
I got it, I just submitted this issue:
[issue 8007](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8007&thanks=8007&ts=1358774289)