# Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected instead

Tags: java, eclipse

Error "Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected instead" is on the dataLength and initialValue parameters (before running, as an underline squiggle). I have also ran clean on the project. Error appears on Luna and Juno of Eclipse, multiple JRE's (1.8-1.7), and multiple workspaces-so I'm guessing it is something on the machine. This machine is Windows 10. This error was not present before. The only thing I can think of on the machine that has changed is installing programs, such as Google Cloud SDK and AWS SDK for Eclipse. I tried uninstalling those and it is still not working.

```
public class Main {

  public Byte[] LCG(Byte[] data, int dataLength, Byte initialValue){
    return data;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the quoted code, it compiles without error.

Comment: The error shows up on my Eclipse Neon. Could it be the way it is configured?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to treat the code as though it were in a different language, not Java. So yeah, could be a configuration thing, applying the wrong language to `.java` files. (This *is* in a `.java` file, right?)

Comment: Yes, it is .java. I have noticed the error is appears on multiple versions of Eclipse, multiple JRE's (1.8-1.7), and multiple workspaces.

Comment: You should post the exact error message, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425114/what-cause-of-formal-parameter-name-expected-occured-in-this-case might be a hint

Comment: I don't see how that would be related because that is the Dart language, not Java.

Comment: Have you tried installing eclipse in a separate place and trying to run it? The eclipse installation might be corrupted, because the code you've written is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you run your code from command line or any other IDE like intellij community or jbuilder or anthing else and see if the problem persists?  first I would isolate if it is windows or ide and then we can review further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this problem because I copied the function signature from an assignment which was in a pdf file. I copied the signature because it was essentially the template for the assignment. But it ended up copying the text format of the string ", int dataLength, Byte initialValue" that was not compatible with Eclipse. I guess it was some wrong type of UTF, or something.

So it had nothing to do with the JDK, in fact the error appeared without a JDK compiler installed.

I just had to delete the text and retype it in Eclipse, and the error went away.

Comment: I will probably give the bounty to Sendi, simply because when I copied the code into Intellij I found the error in the Intellij workspace, and the IntelliJ error was more descriptive which led me to figure out the problem.